# Randomly sampling a "well-mixed" solution of Brownian particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, statistics, brownian-motion

I place $N$ Brownian particles in $V$ liters of solution, shake until I assume that the particles are "well-mixed", and sample and randomly sample an $S$ liter volume.  What is the probability distribution for the number of particles in my sample of $S$ liters?

Comment: With homework like questions, you should include a discussion of your approach to the problem and where you are having difficulty.

Comment: Even if the question was not assigned as homework, it is a homework style question.

Comment: @AdamRedwine, alright, fair enough.